# Do not bind an event handler if has been already bound

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am calling some forms using ajax, and then binding an event handler for every button. The problem is... when I call a new form using ajax the event handler is called again for the new elements and then it's added twice for the previous elements. How can I detect if an event handler is already on an element and not bind it again?

```
function x(){
    $("input:button").click(function(){
        alert('is this called once?');
    });
}

<input type='button' value='Disable me' />
<input type='button' value='Disable me' />
```

```js
function x(){
    $("input:button").click(function(){
        alert('is this called once?');
    });
}

// calling event twice simulating an ajax calling:
x();
x();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='button' value='Disable me' />
<input type='button' value='Disable me' />
```

Comment: Use event delegation so that you only have to set up the event handler once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the click handler actually need to be re-added every time your AJAX request is called? If not, consider revising your code like so:

```js
//Only call this once; new buttons will still trigger it
$(document).on('click', 'input:button', function() {
    alert('is this called once?');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='button' value='Disable me' />
<input type='button' value='Disable me' />
```

By attaching the handler to the document and supplying a selector (`'input:button'`), the function only triggers when clicking on buttons, but will automatically apply to any new buttons that are added after the initial binding.

Comment: Both answers, this one and A.J one, works, I didn't know wich one mark as answer, I going to mark this one, because @Mike McCaughan warning about removing all event handlers. Thank you guys!

Comment: This works, but be careful if you have a SinglePageApp, the listener need to be removed when the element is removed from showed dom. Or you will have a lot of useless (but resource-consuming) listeners

Comment: @Frighi The listener in this case is attached to the document, not the elements. There is only one total listener; it filters events that bubble up from the actual click target using the `'input:button'` selector.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this is use `off` function of jQuery to remove any event attached and then attach it.

This is make sure there is only one click event attached to element.

Example Snippet:

```js
function x() {
  $("input:button").off('click').on('click', function() {
    console.log('is this called once?');
  });
}

// calling event twice simulating an ajax calling:
x();
x();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='button' value='Disable me' />
<input type='button' value='Disable me' />
```

Comment: One thing to note. Using `off('click')` will remove *all* click event handlers on elements matched by the selector. Thus, if you attach an event handler outside the `x` function, those will also be removed. There is an overload of `off` that takes a function, which is the handler to remove, but that would require using a named function for the handler.

Comment: I should also note that there's nothing wrong with this answer, just something to keep in mind when using `off`.